# jquery ui dialog disappears

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

Iam in parent view while clicking the button in the parent view I want to load content of another view in jquery ui dialog. I tried with the following code. but jquery ui dialog initially show the content of the another view, then it doesn't show the content of the another view.

```
 <button id="btn_newtrade" name="btn_newtrade" class="newtrade">New Trade</button>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(function () {
  $('#dialog').dialog({

       autoOpen:false,
       width: 1400, 
       height:600,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'New Trades',
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {

            $(this).load('@Url.Action("NewTrade","Trade")');
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});


$('.newtrade').click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});
 </script>

 <div id="dialog"  style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: What happens at the next time? Do the ajax calls are fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
$('.newtrade').click(function () {
    $('#dialog').load('@Url.Action("NewTrade","Trade")').dialog('open');
});
```

and remove the `open` event handler.

Comment: thanks, it worked fine. close button is not working in the dialog. i want to add another button in the dialog called "Add Trade" when i click the button. it should invoke another controller to add trade but the dialog should not disappear, it should show the same content. thank you